# How to transfer table contents from one database to another database which as user name and password details in SQL

Tags: sql-server, db2, database-migration

I have a table in MS SQL Server which has user specific login and password details. I want to transfer the contents to another table in DB2. How can I transfer/read the password field if its encrypted.

Comment: You possibly can't. How do they become encrypted? Is it encryption or a one-way hash? How is it used in the existing database?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an external stored procedure in DB2, that will read the SQL server data, decrypt it and then reinject it in DB2. The stored procedure should be able to decrypt the data, and then use the DB2's encryption facilities.

The stored procedure will have two connexion, one for DB2, and another one for the remote database (you should provide the driver to the stored procedure).

For the db2 encryption, you can use the routines: ENCRYPT, GET_HINT, SET_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD and DECRYPT - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004211.html

You should be able to decrypt the data from SQL server in order to convert it to re-encrypt it in DB2.

NOTE: If you encrypt the data without the mechanisms provided by the database, but by your application, then you do not need to decrypt the data to transfer it, but just copy the data from one database to the other.